# Access 2003: Count values in table and sort them into a new table

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I'm quite new to Sql, and I sort of have an idea what I would need to use for this idea, however I just can't seem to get it working. I currently have a table that looks like this:

```
|---------------|
|Product | Price|
|Computer|   300|
|Computer|   300|
|Computer|   300|
|Book    |    15|
|Book    |    15|
|---------------|
```

And I wanna store this table as an output:

```
|------------------------|
|Product | Price | Count |
|Computer|    300|      3|
|Book    |     15|      2|
|------------------------|
```

I know I would have to use select distinct and count, however I just have no clue how I should use them to get the result above.
Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select product, price, count(*)
from mytable
group by product, price
```